# How can I get x most valuable companies using some finance APIs?

Tags: web-services, api, finance

I need to find a Web Service which allows me to retrieve the following type of data:

The 30 most valuable companies, and for each company the following information:

- Company name, symbol, state and zipcode
- Current market price of the stock
- Change in the price of the stock since yesterday’s market close.
- Beta value of the stock

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be able to use http://www.xignite.com/ to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect to obtain this information from Forbes. As Steve suggested, you should get it from [xignite.com](http://xignite.com) . Apparently, Forbes makes their data available through them:
http://www.xignite.com/News/PressRelease.aspx?articleid=86

You might also have a look at Yahoo Finance: http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm.

Comment: Thanks @Steve and Arturito for your suggestions. Finally I found the way to obtain this information from Google Finance > Stock Screener. Catching GET requests using Firebug addon in FF I got URLs to services wich return the data in JSON format. [xignite](http://www.xignite.com) also offer this kind of services but its not free.

Answer (score 0):

Here some [example](http://www.google.com/finance?start=0&num=30&q=%5B%28exchange%20%3D%3D%20%22NASDAQ%22%29%20%26%20%28market_cap%20%3E%3D%2048.99%29%20%26%20%28market_cap%20%3C%3D%20524570000000.00006%29%20%26%20%28last_price%20%3E%3D%200%29%20%26%20%28last_price%20%3C%3D%201157%29%20%26%20%28change_today_percent%20%3E%3D%20-101%29%20%26%20%28change_today_percent%20%3C%3D%20408%29%20%26%20%28beta%20%3E%3D%20-3.19%29%20%26%20%28beta%20%3C%3D%205.36%29%5D&restype=company&output=json&noIL=1&sortas=MarketCap) This is not oficial API and there is no documentation.